# C Send/Return array with functions

Tags: c, arrays

I came across this article http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx5.html

but this part confused me: what's the point of returning the array in `send_array_3` if we're already modifying it using `send_array` or `send_array_2` for example? We don't need to return it, right?

```
void send_array(int a[], int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = i*i;
}

void send_array_2(int* a, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = i*i;
}

int* send_array_3(int a[], int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = i*i;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Those functions do not appear in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They say it's not that useful:

> Another difference is that the return value of this latest version of
>   itoa isn't terribly useful. The pointer which this version of itoa
>   returns is always the same as the pointer you handed it. Even if this
>   version of itoa didn't return anything as its formal return value, you
>   could still get your hands on the string it created, since it would be
>   sitting right there in your own array (the one that you passed to
>   itoa). In the case of getline, we had a second thing to return as the
>   formal return value, namely the length of the line we'd just read.

generally you either allocate memory to a pointer and return the array in a function, you pass in the pointer to the array with memory already allocated, and use any return value for error handling, so you can wrap the function in an if statement or whatever.

You could even pass in the address of an array pointer as an int ** (for an int array) allocate the memory, and then not have to return it.

Answer (score 0):

what you got there are just examples how you can handle the problem of "returning" arrays

three different methods are in here and all should work (i would preffer send_array_2)